# How do I display Numbers and Text in C# with XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I am working on a pong clone, and i want to display the player scores onscreen. I don't know how to display it.

Comment: I guess `Console.WriteLine()` is out... :)

Comment: I recommend getting http://www.amazon.com/Learning-XNA-4-0-ebook/dp/B004GTLFIC/ref=kinw_dp_ke?ie=UTF8&m=AG56TWVU5XWC2" - Learning XNA 4.0.  You can read the kindle edition on your computer for $17.59, but you can get a FREE sample that is almost half the entire book.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `SpriteBatch` object has a `DrawString` method that takes:

- a `SpriteFont` which can be created
  in your content project and loaded
  via content.Load
- the `string` you wish to write to the
  screen
- a `Vector2` of the position
  that you want to draw the text at
- the `Color` you wish the text to be.

So for example your draw method might look like this:

```
public void Draw()
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();

    DrawPaddles(spriteBatch);
    DrawBall(spriteBatch);

    // this being the line that answers your question
    spriteBatch.DrawString(scoreFont, playerScore.ToString(), new Vector2(10, 10), Color.White);

    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.drawstring.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You should start your XNA journey at the [XNA Creators Club](http://creators.xna.com/en-US). Even the most basic tutorials output text.

The [XNA Forums](http://forums.xna.com/forums/) are a better resource for XNA-related questions.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has you covered: [How To: Draw Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447673.aspx)